# DeepLink in Facebook Fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, deep-linking

i'm looking for a solution to proceced deeplinks to a facebook fanpage like:

http://www.facebook.com/myfanpage?sk=app_MYAPPID&parameter=2

I need to get the value of parameter in my Fanpage app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `app_data` parameter in your link, and the value of this will be passed to your app in the `signed_request` which is sent on page load. Many developers use JSON encoded data as the value for `app_data` as they want to store multiple values

This is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to find a Solution :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand clearly but what you want is getting parameters from url in facebook is not possible in pagetabs i tried it many times but it won't work.

The only way getting parameters from url in facebook is creating canvas app. Because canvas apps act like domain so you can use whole parameters and urls.

If i missunderstood sorry for it.